# ActiveMQ topics vs RabbitMQ Direct exchanges

Tags: rabbitmq, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, amqp

We are currently looking at ActiveMQ.

Previously we've used RabbitMQ and in particular `Direct exchanges` whereby a producer can send a single message to a broker which then fans this out onto 1:N other queues.

We would like a similar setup in ActiveMQ where the broker holds the configuration for which messages go where, rather than the services sending messages directly to specific queues or consumers needing to subscribe to specific topics.

I've dug into the documentation and found [Virtual Topic Composite Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html#VirtualDestinations-CompositeDestinations) which looks to provide this functionality.

What I am trying to understand now is if this is the ActiveMQ recommended approach and if there are any pitfalls I should be wary of?

Any ActiveMQ war stories much appreciated!

Comment: You might take a look at ActiveMQ Artemis which is planned to become ActiveMQ 6. Although it is a completely new broker implementation it has strong backwards compatibility with ActiveMQ 5.x clients (e.g. supports OpenWire, 5.x STOMP conventions, AMQP 1.0, etc.). Also, the broker's core addressing model fits more with what you're looking for.  You can define addresses and the queues they route to along with the type of routing semantics to use (e.g. anycast or multicast).  Check it out at https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/.